# I cannot access the data entered into an edit textbox in a databound gridview in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have created a gridview that now functions exactly the way I need it to, but I need to implement editing to the gridview.  This is a little funky as I will have to create an xml string to feed into an api instead of updating the table directly.  Each of my rows have an edit button.  Clicking on the edit button converts the cells into texboxes populated with the initial values as expected and converts the edit button to an "update" and a "cancel" button.  I have implemented a procedure which successfully fires when the "update" button is clicked.  The problem is that I cannot seem to get the value that is typed into the text box.

I have tried inspecting the text box and using the information there to call the findControl function, I have tried the Request.Form function too, but these did not work, they returned a null value.  The BEST result I have gotten is by hard coding the cells and control array addresses like this "((TextBox)(row.Cells[5].Controls[0])).Text".  When I use this method I get the proper cell, in this case the status, but it pulls the original value instead of the value that the user enters.  For example, in this case, the original value is "Active" and I type "Canceled" into the text box and hit update, the value of "Active" will be returned in my statement.

I'm happy to provide more information or clarification if needed.  Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

The Gridview definition:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" >
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom"
       RowStyle-Wrap="true" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" OnDataBound ="OnDataBound" AllowSorting="True" HeaderStyle-Height="50px"
       OnSorting="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="reportData" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
       CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" OnRowEditing ="GridView_RowEditing" 
       OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView_RowCancellingEdit" OnRowUpdating="GridView_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames ="PropID,Project Type" >
       
       
       <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
       <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
<HeaderStyle Wrap="True" Height="50px" BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>

       <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />

<RowStyle Wrap="True" BackColor="#F7F7DE"></RowStyle>
       <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
       <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
       <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
       <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
       <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
   </asp:GridView>
```

The construction of the Gridview in code behind:

```
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlString, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            BoundField bf = new BoundField
            {
                HeaderText = "State",
                DataField = "State"
            };
            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf);

            bf = new BoundField
            {
                HeaderText = "Status",
                DataField = "Status"
            };

            bf.ItemStyle.CssClass = "statusField";
            bf.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "statusHead";


            GridView1.Columns.Add(bf);
```

there are other fields, but you get the idea

```
            GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
```

on gridview_rowUpdating:

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]

            for (int i = 0; i< GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string text = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[5].Controls[0])).Text;
            }
```

Comment: I have played with this a bit longer and basically cleaned up my code a bit, but in my investigation I have discovered that this issue is ONLY happening on the first row in my grid.  If I edit a different row, the user entered value is returned via the textbox.  I do have the databind in pageload and it is outside of my "IsPostBack" check, but if I wrap that databind inside the check, my entire grid disappears when I click the edit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was due to my gridhelper groups causing the row number to be off.